# same key coming in different reducers in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, reducers

I am experiencing something very strange. I am getting same key in different reducers. I just printed and collected the key and values. My reducer code looks like this.

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

System.out.println("The key is "+ key.toString());

while(values.hasNext()){


        Text value=values.next();

        key.set("");
        output.collect(key, value);

  }
 }
```

The output on console is

```
  The key is 111-00-1234195967001
The key is 1234529857009
The key is 1234529857009
14/01/06 20:11:16 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
14/01/06 20:11:16 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
14/01/06 20:11:16 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
14/01/06 20:11:16 INFO mapred.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' to hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/joboutput11
14/01/06 20:11:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
14/01/06 20:11:18 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' done.
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 23
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=289074
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=5707
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=19185
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=1254215
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=270933
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=5707
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=5633
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=5
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=10
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=5583
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=991539200
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=0
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input bytes=289074
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=627
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=5
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=3
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=7
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
14/01/06 20:11:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=5
```

The key 1234529857009 is repeated twice which is abnormal. Any Ideas why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: Could you check the values and let us know how many values are provided with each key and how many of them are distinct?

Comment: Thanks. There are 2 distinct keys i.e. 111-00-1234195967001 and 1234529857009. First one produce 2 values and second key provides 3 values. But these three are split and 2 values come in one reducer and the third one in different reducer. Now as simplefish said it is a normal behavior which is again a problem. I explained in a comment to simplefish reply what problem it is creating for me. I am using a single node.

Answer (score 0):

Due to hadoop's [speculative execution](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/hadoop/9780596521974/task-execution/id2751946) it is not guaranteed that each key only goes to a reducer exactly once during an execution. What you want to watch out for is the completed output, not the in-process state. So if you replace that reducer with an identity reducer, and you still see repeated lines in the output, then you have something to worry about. Otherwise, it could be working as intended, since hadoop may generate multiple reducer jobs but will keep only the output of one of them (usually the one that completes first).

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is creating a problem for me. With every key I have a value which is a date. All the similar key/value are collected in the in a  array and their dates/value is subtracted from each other and the difference is sent to HDFS. Now if similar key is coming in different reducers then the array is incomplete and the output is not the one I want. So what is the alternate in this case?

Comment: Just to let you know that the key which is coming in different reducers also has different values. There are 3 unique values for the key and 2 of them are coming in one reducer and the third one comes to a different reducer which makes no sense. Speculative execution should give redundant values in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

@shujaat - @simplefish is not saying output getting split is a normal behavior rather multiple reducers processing a single key is a normal behavior. From the Definitive guide on Speculative Execution below.

Go to the JobTracker.jsp page and under the job check the value for `Reduce Input Records` and `Reduce Output Records` in the `Map-Reduce Framework` section to see whether they are the same.

> It’s important to understand that speculative execution does not work by launching two duplicate tasks at about the same time so they can race each other. This would be wasteful of cluster resources. Rather, a speculative task is launched only after all the tasks for a job have been launched, and then only for tasks that have been running for some time (at least a minute), and have failed to make as much progress, on average,
>   as the other tasks from the job. When a task completes successfully, any duplicate tasks that are running are killed since they are no longer needed. So if the original task completes before the speculative task then the speculative task is killed; on the other hand, if the speculative task finishes first, then the original is killed.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I understood what simplefish said and what you say. The issue I am facing is weird. With same key there are are different reduce groups. See the output above. It says I have 3 different reduce groups while I am saying it should be two because there are 2 keys. I have also turned the speculative execution off. The output is still the same.